# bash delete no more than x files

Tags: bash

I'd like to delete all files in a specific folder (and it's subfolder).
But i'd like to delete no more than x file.

Until now I always used `find -f -delete /path/to/dir/*`

TLDR explaination:

This folder is a folder for "cached" thumbs, i want them to regenerate, but not all at the same time, because it represent ~30Go of images.

I should also use a find based on the creation time, but most of them where created by scripts and come in group where on 5 month no creation and on 1 day, 5Go.

Comment: Have you read `man find`?

Comment: `find ... -print | sort | head -n X | xargs rm -f`

Comment: So how do you decide which N files to delete? Just the first N alphabetically?

Comment: here is the final bash command I used : 

find '/path' -type f -ctime +365 -mindepth 2 | head -n 100 | xargs rm

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
find /dir -type f -ctime +365 | head -n 100 | xargs rm
```

Will only match files older than 1 year. This way you are guaranteed to not always delete the same group of files.

This assumes you have no filenames containing any newline character.

Doing it the right would require keeping track of files upon creation, but it's probably too late for that.

Comment: thanks Zsolt ans Vincent I'll try it soon!

Answer (score 0):

You should try

```
find /dir -type f -iname '*jpg' -print | head -100 | xargs rm
```

This basically searches only for `jpg`s but you can modify it. It will delete the first 100, but you can change that too in the `head -100` part.

But this is just a ... wrong idea. As you are removing the first 100, nothing guarantees, that the regenerated ones won't be the first ones for the next delete job.